# Output stream on powershell for SSH calls

Tags: php, powershell, ssh

My PHP script (in Linux) is not printing my values on screen, however it prints a Warning message.

e.g.

This is my php code:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'powershell "c:\remoteScript.ps1" -$NotificationID "5359f76f888ddf35b889dedf"');
$string = stream_get_contents($stream);
echo "Powershell output: ". $string;
```

This is my powershell code:

```
Write-Warning "This is a test"
```

And this is what PHP is writing:

> Powershell output: WARNING: You should update your PowerShell to
>   PowerShell 2.0 version.

**QUESTION:** How can I catch the the stream returned by Powershell?

Comment: You should probably start with updating PowerShell to at least v2.0, 1.0 is almost 5 years out of date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** we need to tell ssh2_exec whether to wait/block until the remote process  finishes [search for "block" on this page to see an example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php).

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'powershell \'C:\scripts\remoteVeeamClientSummary.ps1\' -Client \''. $Client. '\' -NotificationID \''. $NotificationID. '\'');

stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

return stream_get_contents($stream);
```

and powershell:

```
Write-Output $result
```